# How to update one to many association in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my app, I have one to many relationship between shows and episodes. Shows can have many episodes. When creating an episode I am able to build an association to the show by doing this:

```
  def create(conn, %{"episode" => episode_params}) do
    show = Repo.get!(Show, episode_params["show_id"])
    changeset =
      show
      |> build_assoc(:episodes)
      |> Episode.changeset(episode_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _post} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Episode created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: show_path(conn, :show, show))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

How can I best update the episodes association to a show? This is what I have now.

```
  def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "episode" => episode_params}) do
    episode = Repo.get!(Episode, id)
    changeset = Episode.changeset(episode, episode_params)

    case Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, episode} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Episode updated successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: episode_path(conn, :show, episode))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "edit.html", episode: episode, changeset: changeset)
    end
 end
```

Comment: You could just add `show_id` to the allowed fields of the `cast` in `Episode.changeset/2` and let the foreign key constraint handle invalid `show_id` values. Is there any reason not to do that?

Comment: @Dogbert You're right! Still learning. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have some requirements like not allowing changes to `show_id` from some actions, the simplest way would be to add `show_id` to the list of allowed fields in the call to `cast` in `Episode.changeset/2`, and let the database handle invalid `show_id` values using foreign key constraints.

```
defmodule MyApp.Episode
  ...
  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:show_id, ...]) # add :show_id here
  end
end
```

and then just pass `episode_params` directly to `changeset` in both `create` and `update`:

```
def create(conn, %{"episode" => episode_params}) do
  changeset = Episode.changeset(%Episode{}, episode_params)
  ...
end
```

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "episode" => episode_params}) do
  episode = Repo.get!(Episode, id)
  changeset = Episode.changeset(episode, episode_params)
  ...
end
```

Make sure your migration added `show_id` field using `references(...)` or that you manually added the database constraint. Something like:

```
create table(:episodes) do
  ...
  add :show_id, references(:shows, on_delete: :nothing)
  ...
end
```